# How can I check if a string is all uppercase in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

There is a Javascript/Jquery boolean function to test if a string is all uppercase?

example of matching:

```
"hello" => false
"Hello" => false
"HELLO" => true
```

Comment: If I google for `"How can I check if a string is all uppercase in JavaScript? [duplicate]"` I find this question

Comment: Same, this is the top result for testing if an entire string is uppercase.  Furthermore testing an entire string is a bit different than checking a specific character.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
function isUpperCase(str) {
    return str === str.toUpperCase();
}


isUpperCase("hello"); // false
isUpperCase("Hello"); // false
isUpperCase("HELLO"); // true
```

You could also augment `String.prototype`:

```
String.prototype.isUpperCase = function() {
    return this.valueOf().toUpperCase() === this.valueOf();
};


"Hello".isUpperCase(); // false
"HELLO".isUpperCase(); // true
```

Comment: `isUpperCase("123"); // true`

Comment: To reiterate Derek's comment... a string consisting of only numbers will return true, incorrectly indicating all upper case.

Comment: @Stuart Why incorrectly ? I guess the problem here is that a string with no characters possessing the uppercase-capability is not allowed on the true side of is-uppercase ?

Comment: @Bitterblue Basically, that's my understanding. There should be all uppercase characters and numbers are neither.

Comment: @Stuart I'm not arguing, just saying. What if you need to know if a member is a constant and not a variable? And all you have is the name: `myVariable`, `MY_CONSTANT`, `MY_CONSTANT_123`.

Comment: @Bitterblue I don't think there is an easy way to resolve that short of adopting a policy of "no numbers in constants". I suppose you could create a function that would rely on the ES6 const so that when you attempt to change a value, if it is a constant, it would throw an error. This might not work in certain browsers though. Easier to adopt a naming policy.

Comment: `str.toUpperCase() === str && /\p{Lu}/u.test(str)` also checks if `str` contains an uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant avoiding the problem with strings consisting of numbers only

Comment: isUpperCase("GAUß"); // logically false, visually true - because the character 'ß' is classified as lowercase - it didn't have an official uppercased version until 2017. Older data-sets might have this issue. Fix : `str.replace("ß","SS") === str.toUpperCase()`

Comment: Please Note: empty string, numbers and symbols will validate as true. use regex `/^[A-Z]*$/` if you want to check for only uppercase. still +1

Answer (score 35):

I must write at least one sentence here because they don't like short answers here, but this is the simplest solution I can think of:

```
s.toUpperCase() === s
```

Comment: +1 for the two sentences !

Comment: Ha ha, someone took it personally. Good for you (I got a downvote)!

Comment: I ***`LOVE`*** short answers!

Comment: Most simplist and streightfoward solution.

Answer (score 16):

Here's another option:

```
function isUpperCase(str) {
  return (/^[^a-z]*$/).test(str);
}
```

Comment: Nice, but by changing the regex to `/^[A-Z]*$/` it will discard numbers and punctuations too.

Comment: Be cautious of using the above regex as it rejects strings like "ABC123" which is clearly uppercase. Instead, use this regex: `function isUpper(str) {
    return !/[a-z]/.test(str) && /[A-Z]/.test(str)
}`. Strings like "123" or "WE23a" returns false while strings like "W390" returns true.

Comment: @AlienKevin Are you referring to the regex in this answer? It does not reject the string "ABC123"; it rejects any string that contains any lowercase letters.

Comment: @DanTao Sorry, my mistake. Your regex does not reject "ABC123" but it does accept "123" which is not uppercase. That's why I proposed a more robust version.

Answer (score 4):

Just use:

```
if(mystring === mystring.toUpperCase())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = "HELLO";
var upper = test.toUpperCase();

return test === upper; // true

// other example

var test = "Hello";
var upper = test.toUpperCase();

return test === upper; // false
```